# How to add RDFa to fields in a view?

Tags: 7, views, rdf

I have installed a Drupal 7 views module called Islandora Solr Views and I can create views from the Islandora solr search results. My next goal is to add some semantic data to these fields but after searching around several days, I still can't find a way to do that.

At the moment the HTML for one of the fields look like this:

```
<div class="views-field views-field-mods-name-Author-ms">
  <span class="views-label views-label-mods-name-Author-ms">Author: </span>
  <span class="field-content">Mr LLoyd Marshall</span>
</div>
```

I want to add the following RDFa data the to the field:

```
<span property="dc:creator" href="http://www.example.com/people/R12345">
    <span vocab="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/" typeof="Person" 
             about="http://www.example.com/people/R12345">
        <span property="name">Mr LLoyd Marshall</span>
    </span>
</span>
```

Is there a module to do that? If not how should I go about achieving this?

According to [the post *Allow custom attributes on Semantic Field wrapper tags*](https://drupal.org/node/1338854), I wonder if there is a module to do this at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Fences modules to change the output of a field to a span as you have here. Then use https://drupal.org/project/semanticviews to wrap the span field with semantic markup.   I'm on my phone gluck